# Error event listener doesn't execute function when page loads

Tags: javascript

I have a page that contains some report pictures. Under each image, there are 4 buttons that change the image's src when clicked. 
I've written a short script (**imageValidation.js**) that checks if the image has loaded successfully and if not, runs a function that changes images src to generic 'file not found' picture.

The problem is that I want the script to replace replace the 'broken' image srcs when the page load initially, which it doesn't. However, when I change the pictures by clicking on the buttons, the script works fine.

To give an example, I deleted the **01UR(All).jpeg**. When the page loads I see generic broken picture icon. But when I click on the **All Cycles** button, the image changes to the **ReportUnavailable.jpeg** as desired.

I've tried executing the code in **onload** attribute in body section. Also tried moving the script tag to head and to the beginning of the body section.

How should it be done correctly?

Here's the HTML:

```
<body>    
<div>
    <img id="UR_chart" class="Reportpicture" src="reports/01UR(All).jpeg" />
</div>
<div class="submenu">
    <button id="UR_all" onclick="changeChart('UR_chart', 'reports/01UR(All).jpeg')">
        All Cycles
    </button>
    <button id="UR_c1" onclick="changeChart('UR_chart', 'reports/01UR(C1).jpeg')">
        Cycle 1
    </button>
    <button id="UR_c2" onclick="changeChart('UR_chart', 'reports/01UR(C2).jpeg')">
        Cycle 2
    </button>
    <button id="UR_c3" onclick="changeChart('UR_chart', 'reports/01UR(C3).jpeg')">
        Cycle 3
    </button>
</div>

<!-- more divs -->

<script src="../Scripts/imageValidation.js"></script>
</body>
```

The **image validation** script:

```
/*imageValidation.js*/ 
var reportPix = document.getElementsByClassName("Reportpicture");

for(var i = 0; i < reportPix.length; i++)
{
    reportPix[i].addEventListener("error", noImageFound);
}

function noImageFound()
{
    this.src = 'ReportUnavailable.jpeg';

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing two things here.
One after window.onload all images are checked and if they have a natrualWidth and naturalHeight of 0 then they are replaced. This should take care of any images that got loaded before the event got registered.

The Event listener is still registered and will be called for the cases where the image is changed.

```js
function changeChart() {
 reportPix[0].src = "blank1.gif";

}
window.onload = checkImages;

var reportPix = document.getElementsByClassName("Reportpicture");
for(var i = 0; i < reportPix.length; i++) {
  reportPix[i].addEventListener("error", noImageFound);
}

function checkImages() {
 for(var i = 0; i < reportPix.length; i++) {
  if (reportPix[i].naturalHeight === 0 && reportPix[i].naturalWidth === 0) {
   noImageFound(reportPix[i]);
  }
 }
}

function noImageFound(obj) {
 if (obj.target) {
  obj.target.src = "https://img.clipartfest.com/cee7c57a2d96b3117b12d85fc6b6d6fc_photo-not-available-large-picture-not-available-clipart_325-384.png";
 } else {
  obj.src = "https://img.clipartfest.com/cee7c57a2d96b3117b12d85fc6b6d6fc_photo-not-available-large-picture-not-available-clipart_325-384.png";
 }
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img id="UR_chart" class="Reportpicture" src="reports/01UR(All).jpeg" />
</div>
<div class="submenu">
    <button id="UR_all" onclick="changeChart('UR_chart', 'reports/01UR(All).jpeg')">
        All Cycles
    </button>
    <button id="UR_c1" onclick="changeChart('UR_chart', 'reports/01UR(C1).jpeg')">
        Cycle 1
    </button>
    <button id="UR_c2" onclick="changeChart('UR_chart', 'reports/01UR(C2).jpeg')">
        Cycle 2
    </button>
    <button id="UR_c3" onclick="changeChart('UR_chart', 'reports/01UR(C3).jpeg')">
        Cycle 3
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: unfortunately executing this after window.onload didn't work for me. The src of incorrectly loaded imgs doesn't change when the page is loaded.

Comment: it seems to work now, although it doesn't always replacing all the imgs (there are 7 of them), not sure why. Maybe it's all because I'm storing this page on SharePoint server (although that shouldn't be the case since the page is only stored there). Anyway I think this is as close as it gets to the working solution, thanks for the help!

Comment: I updated my code, please take a look. I think that would fix all your images upon first load.